# elements in the cells of the table are not on the same level

Tags: css

I need to make a page like this(task)
[image]

But my page looks like this.
[image]

**Elements in the second cell are not on the same level as elements in the cell 1 and cell 3. Also two buttons on page are not on the same level too - button with price is a little higher than button with text.**
How to solve this problem?

Every cell in my table looks like this

```
<td id="cell2">
            <img src="pic2.png">
            <p class="specs">
                 Тип: Светильник потолочный<br>
                 Фабрика: ST Luce<br>
                 Страна: Италия<br>
                </p>
                <p class="desc">
                    Светильник потолочный ST Luce<br> серии SL600,<br> артикул SL600.542.05
                </p>
                <button class="price">6784р</button>
                <button class="order">Заказать</button>
    </td>
```

Link to the fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/dNfvz/1/
Also how to set space between cells?

Comment: You'll need to set a height for the `desc`, as for the second element has more 'text' in the `desc`, thus pushing the rest down further. http://jsfiddle.net/dNfvz/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other answers are not correct. You can't use positioning in table cells. **So position: relative; for a td is not possible!** So you can't archive what you want with tables and position relative.

**Option 1:**

Wrap the content above the buttons with a div and give it a fixed height. Then you can garantuee that the buttons are at the same position.
The tds need vertical-align: top; to align the content at the top.

**Option 2:**

I personally don't like tables so i tried to get rid of them. I made an example with your code.

```
<body>
<div id="container">
    <div id="table">
        <div>
            <div id="cell1">
                <div class="cell_wrap">
                    <img src="pic1.png" />
                    <p class="specs">Тип: Спот
                        <br/>Фабрика: Novotech
                        <br/>Страна: Венгрия
                        <br/>
                    </p>
                    <p class="desc">Спот Novotech серии Crystal-LED,
                        <br/>артикул 357012</p>
                    <div class="button_wrap">
                        <button class="price">735р</button>
                        <button class="order">Заказать</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="cell2">
                <img src="pic2.png" />
                <p class="specs">Тип: Светильник потолочный
                    <br/>Фабрика: ST Luce
                    <br/>Страна: Италия
                    <br/>
                </p>
                <p class="desc">Светильник потолочный ST Luce
                    <br/>серии SL600,
                    <br/>артикул SL600.542.05</p>
                <div class="button_wrap">
                    <button class="price">735р</button>
                    <button class="order">Заказать</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="cell3">
                <img src="pic3.png" />
                <p class="specs">Тип: Подвес
                    <br/>Фабрика: ArteLamp
                    <br/>Страна: Италия
                    <br/>
                </p>
                <p class="desc">Подвес ArteLamp серии JERSEY,
                    <br/>артикул A8543LM-6GO</p>
                <div class="button_wrap">
                    <button class="price">735р</button>
                    <button class="order">Заказать</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Qd48A/

The only problem I still have is that you have to set a fixed height for the rows. I don't know exactly your situation but maybe for it's no problem.

Answer (score 2):

Vertical align top is what you are looking for

```
table td {
    border: 2px solid #A09A82;
    padding: 5px 5px;
    vertical-align:top; //add this
}
```

The button will require positioning to keep them on the same level, for example with position absolute

http://jsfiddle.net/dNfvz/3/

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `valign="top"` to your `td`'s and then position your buttons to the bottom of the cell with css `position` :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will work for you: http://jsfiddle.net/dNfvz/2/

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div class="action">
    <button class="price">735р</button>
    <button class="order">Заказать</button>
</div>
```

---

```
/** CSS **/
table td {
    border: 2px solid #A09A82;
    padding: 5px 5px 50px;
    position: relative;
}

div.action {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

changes

```
   table td { 
       position: relative;
        border: 2px solid #A09A82;
        padding: 5px 5px;
    }

    button.price, button.order {
       position: absolute;
       bottom: 3px;
    }

    button.price {
        left: 20px;
        background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #b5b4b3), color-stop(1, #141414) );
        background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #b5b4b3 5%, #141414 100% );
        background-color:#b5b4b3;
        border-top-left-radius:20px;
        border-top-right-radius:20px;
        border-bottom-right-radius:20px;
        border-bottom-left-radius:20px;
        text-indent:-11.25px;
        border:1px solid #ded5de;
        display:inline-block;
        color:#ffffff;
        font-family:Courier New;
        font-size:15px;
        /*font-weight:bold;*/
        font-style:normal;
        height:25px;
        line-height:25px;
        width:75px;
        text-decoration:none;
        text-align:center;
        pointer-events:none;

    }

    button.order {
        right: 20px;
        background:-webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #ffffff), color-stop(1, #bfbfbf) );
        background:-moz-linear-gradient( center top, #ffffff 5%, #bfbfbf 100% );
        background-color:#ffffff;
        border-top-left-radius:20px;
        border-top-right-radius:20px;
        border-bottom-right-radius:20px;
        border-bottom-left-radius:20px;
        text-indent:0px;
        border:1px solid #ffffff;
        display:inline-block;
        color:#db1818;
        font-family:Courier New;
        font-size:12px;
        font-weight:bold;
        font-style:normal;
        height:25px;
        line-height:25px;
        width:84px;
        text-decoration:none;
        text-align:center;
        margin-left: -18pt;
       margin-top: 50pt;

}
```